# derivation of transport equation

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

The amount of pollutant in the interval at time $t$ is $M=\int_0^bu(x,t)dx$ .At later time t+h,the same molecules of pollutant have moved to the right by $ch$ centimetres.

$M=\int_0^bu(x,t)dx=\int_{ch}^{b+ch}u(x,t+h)dx$.

Differentiating with respect to b, we get
$u(b,t)=u(b+ch,t+h)$.
Can some one please explain to me how the expression after differentiating with respect to b is obtained $u(b,t)=u(b+ch,t+h)$.  ?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are asking, but the equation $u(b,t)=u(b+ch,t+h)$ is obtained by the "differentiation under the integral sign" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign

Answer (score 0):

Let $U$ be the $x$ antiderivative of $u$, so $U_x=u$, by the fundamental theorem of calculus we have:

$U(b,t)-U(0,t)=U(b+ch,t+ch)-U(ch,t+ch)$, differentiate with respect to $b$ and we have:

$U_b(b,t)=U_b(b+ch,t)$, but $U_b=u$, so:

$u(b,t)=u(b+ch,t)$

Comment: How does $U_b=u$